# How to create a letter progression for a variable in a loop in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to change a variable (lett) to the next letter in the alphabet on each iteration of a loop. I have to also be able to set this variable at the beginning of the script to a certain letter (and the initial letter will vary depending on the use of the script). I started with creating the following bit of code:

Initial script (when I was still learning):

```
while lett_trig == 2:
    if set_lett == 2:
        lett = "a"
    if set_lett == 3:
        lett = "b"
    if set_lett == 4:
        lett = "c"
    if set_lett == 5:
        lett = "d"
    if set_lett == 6:
        lett = "e"
    if set_lett == 7:
        lett = "f"
    if set_lett == 8:
        lett = "g"
    if set_lett == 9:
        lett = "h"
#... and this goes on till it reaches if set_let == 27: lett = "z"

    set_lett += 1
    if set_lett == 28:
        set_lett = 2
    print lett

# set_lett starts at two because I left set_lett == 1 to create a space (" ")
```

This is of course a simplification of a larger script.
**This is the only simplification I could come up with:**

```
lett_trig = 2
x = 0

a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

while lett_trig == 2:
    lett = a[x]
    x += 1
    if x == 26:
        x = 0
```

Is there any other way to mathematically change from one letter to another? Through some binary conversion operation? or is the list-way the most efficient?

---

Answer: after going through all the answers and testing them for efficiency, I found the dict function to be the fastest (and cleanest). An example of the code:

```
import string

letter_map = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase[1:] + string.ascii_lowercase[0]))
lett1 = "d"

while ord(lett2) < 122:
    print lett1
    lett1 = letter_map[lett1]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `itertools.cycle`:

```
import itertools
import string
letters = itertools.cycle(string.lowercase)
```

With this, `letters` is an infinite sequence of letters, running from a to z repeatedly. You can use this in a `while` loop by calling `letters.next()` or in a `for` loop by imposing a termination condition in some fashion, e.g., `itertools.islice`.

You can put this together into a function:

```
def cyclic_letters(start='a'):
    i = string.lowercase.index(start)
    letts = string.lowercase[i:] + string.lowercase[:i]
    return itertools.cycle(letts)
```

The `cyclic_letters` function also allows the initial letter in the sequence to be selected, defaulting to `'a'`.

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary that shows the next letter for any given letter. You can create a dictionary for that, such as by:

```
letter_map = dict(zip(string.lowercase, string.lowercase[1:] + string.lowercase[0]))
```

This is just a dictionary, so using, e.g., `letter_map['c']` will produce `'d'`.

In the above, `string.lowercase` is just a string containing the lowercase letters. The value will depend on your locale. If you only want `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, regardless of locale, you can substitute `string.ascii_lowercase` or just give the explicit string.

Comment: I would only add that `string.lowercase` is just a **string**  `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\x83\x90\x9a\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa...'` (for those not acquainted with it, it may look like a function or some other object) thus making it more difficult to understand the code snippet.

Comment: is there any way to call a specific letter from the cycle? For example if I set lett_1 from "h" to "i" then want to set lett_2 from "c" to "d"?

Comment: @ovgolovin `string.lowercase` is just `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` here, with Python 2.7. Presumably the extra characters in your comment are unicode, with Python 3 (which I don't have installed on the computer I'm using right now).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 either. The output of `string.lowercase` I got from the docs: `help(string)`. My locale is Russian. I've just tested, `string.lowercase` gives `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\x83\x90\x9a\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb8\xba\xbc\xbe\xbf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'`. So, if one needs `abcd...xyz`, they should use `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: @user1042034 No, there is not; this matches the updating once per iteration in your question. You could use multiple instances of the generator, each of which would be updated independently. If what you really want is a table showing how to make the changes from one letter to the next, please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @ovgolovin Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Thanks, I'm not set on a method to progress from one letter to the next, but (and I will edit my question) it is important to be able to set the initial letter from the start (which won't always be "a") as well as set multiple variables to their next sequenced letter (although as you said, multiple instances of the generator would work). It seems like this method might not work for initially setting the variables though?

Comment: @user1042034 You could use `itertools.dropwhile` or `itertools.islice` to get rid of the initial letters that you don't want. Perhaps simpler would be to use a dictionary mapping from one letter to the next; I've edited that into the answer.

Comment: @user1042034 I've edited in a function definition that allows the generator to start with whatever letter you like.

Comment: After testing on a 500k+ loop, it's faster (and cleaner) using the dict function. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
chr(x + ord("a"))
```

where `x` is an integer in the range 0 to 25.

[`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) returns the ASCII code of a character, and [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) turns an ASCII code into a character again.  In ASCII, the lower case letters all appear consecutively (in contrast to EBCDIC for those who still remember).

Comment: This seems very clean, and allows flexibility, but when tested against my list method it actually requires more processing to execute. When executing a very large loop it took a few seconds longer.

Comment: @user1042034: You never mentioned you are after performance.  In that case, you should of course replace `ord("a")` by a hard-coded `97`.  Probably you should use a completely different algorithm for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: simplifying the code to just: lett = chr(x) \n x += 1 is still about a second slower then the list method when run in a 500 000 times loop. I still like how clean it is though.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I use ASCII math in my own C code and I'm totally fine with your answer. With the shift to Unicode for everything, though, is that still a good idea?

Comment: @Kirk: This depends on what the OP actually wants to do.  From the post, I think it is looping over the letters `a` to `z` in some way, so it doesn't matter whether to use Unicode or ASCII -- the Unicode code point of them are the same as their ASCII codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
idx = 0
while condition:
    lett = chr(idx + ord('a'))
    idx += 1
    if idx == 26:
        idx = 0
```

See [ord](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord), [chr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing, you might be interested in `string.lowercase` and it's cousins.

```
>>> import string
>>> for let in string.lowercase:
...    print let
...
a
b
c
(etc)
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII codes for letters are consecutive. So 65 = 'A', 66 = 'B' and so on - [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you could use a normal loop.

Start at 97 (lower case 'a') and loop using normal incrementing and then convert the loop counter to it's equivalent character for output.